# Detect column drag or resize in NSTableView while it is happening in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I am working with an NSTableView in a macOS application and am trying to keep an arrow image next to the header drag bar of the currently sorted column. I have successfully been able to place the arrow next to the drag bar, but it only updates its position when the drag is released. I need it to update its position while the column-drag/resize is happening.

I have tried using the `tableView(_:mouseDraggedWith:)`, `mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent)` and `tableView(_:didDrag:)` delegate methods, but the mouseDragged functions don't trigger during column resizing, and the `didDrag` method triggers only upon mouse release.

I have also attempted to use the NSTableView.columnDidMoveNotification notification, but it also only triggers after the drag is released.

How can I detect the drag or resize of a column while it's happening, prior to the mouse click being released?

Comment: Is [`setIndicatorImage(_:in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1534381-setindicatorimage) sufficient for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTableView` has a method, [`setIndicatorImage(_:in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1534381-setindicatorimage), that puts an image at the right end of a column header (where the sort indicator may be displayed).

Comment: The only issue I'm having with `setIndicatorImage` is that the image proportion is a bit askew despite attempts to override the NSImage proportions.

If that solution isn't as obvious here, feel free to ignore.

Comment: Your other main option is to subclass `NSTableHeaderCell`. It will definitely be more complicated though.